# Can we restore to previous commit in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to restore data from neo4j?
I just lost all data and want to restore to previous state of neo4j.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you have disk backups?  Your neo4j database is just a directory on disk.  So if you have a backup of your disk, you can take a snapshot of whatever that directory was at some previous point in time.  But AFAIK, there's nothing built into neo4j that will do this for you.

Comment: I have directory but how to take it to previous day? and I was using 1.9.6

Comment: How do you do backups of your disk?  How you would get it back to the previous day depends on how you did your backups.

Comment: I dont have backup. I thought there could be a way using transaction logs.

Comment: I don't think so.  But wait on others to have a chance at answering, hopefully someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: You can contact neo technology support (http://support.neotechnology.com) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4J Server must be configured to run backups. If your server wasn't configured to create backups, then there is not a way to restore your data using Neo4J. This is controlled by the Neo4J config option `online_backup_enabled`.

This feature is enabled by default in Neo4J 2.1.6 Enterprise. However, you have to manually run a backup in order for one to be created. So, unless you ran a backup, then you aren't going to find one which was automatically taken anywhere on your system. Sorry :-(

In the future, you can configure and run backups following the [Neo4J documentation.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/backup-introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks, Before I was using older version of neo4j and didn't setup backup.